# Domain in polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have this domain $A=\{ (x,y) \in R^2 : x^2+y^2 \ge4, x^2+y^2-2x-2y\le0 \}$

It's right the change in polar coordinates : $$\{ (r,\theta): \theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}], r \in [2,2(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)] \}$$

I'm using this for $\int_A {y\over(x^2+y^2)} dx dy$.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Are you asking if the translation into polar coordinates is correct?

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram? Your range for $\theta$ makes sense. Think again about what it is for $r$.

Comment: why the range of r isn't right?

Comment: The first condition says $|r| \ge 2$

Comment: i've edit.It's right now?

Comment: Why are your intervals open?

Comment: the result of the integral is $5+{\pi \over 2}$?

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

If $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y = r\sin \theta$ then $4 \leq x^2 + y^2 = r^2 $. Moreover

$$r^2 -2r(\cos \theta + \sin \theta) \leq 0  \Rightarrow \Big(r-(\cos\theta + \sin\theta)\Big)^2 \leq  (\cos\theta + \sin\theta)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture.  Your conditions specify points outside a circle $x^2+y^2\geq 2^2$ and inside another circle $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2\leq (\sqrt{2})^2$.  You can determine the intersection of the two circles and find angles from there, or otherwise note that the intersection points are $(2,0)$ and $(0,2)$.

For $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ you need to specify bounds on $r$ (between the two circles), the easier one being the lower bound of $r=2$ for the circle centered at the origin.  For the circle centered at $(1,1)$, you can look at
$$
x^2+y^2-2(x+y)=0
$$
in polar coordinates
$$
r^2-2r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)=0
$$
and solve for $r$ to get
$$
r=2(\sin\theta+\cos\theta).
$$
So the region is
$$
\{(r,\theta) \ : \ \theta\in[0,\pi/2], \ 2\leq r\leq 2(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)\}
$$
as you've written.

For the integral, you get
$$
\int_A\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}dxdy=\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi/2}\int_{r=2}^{r=2(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)}\frac{r\sin\theta}{r^2}rdrd\theta=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin^2\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta) d\theta
$$
which you can integrate however you want.